# Print out array of objects to console

Tags: c#, arrays, object, reflection

I have array of object, how can I print its contain to console ?

I need to print the properties and its value.

```
object[] attrs;
attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

I must use reflection but I dont know how to use it.

Comment: So, what has your research revealed so far?  Why doesn't it help to answer your question?

Comment: `foreach(var item in attrs) .......`

Comment: I think you didn't get my point, I need to print the properties name and its value

Comment: @Nuha Alshmlany make sure to check my edit, it's probably what you're after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use reflection. Here's a sample:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string obj1 = "a string";
        int obj2 = 12;
        DateTime obj3 = DateTime.Today;

        object[] obj_array = { obj1, obj2, obj3 };

        foreach (object obj in obj_array)
        {
            //Print value
            Console.WriteLine("Value: " + obj.ToString());

            //Print property names
            Console.WriteLine("Property Names:");
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

EDIT: sorry you probably wanted to retrieve the property values of the object itself. In that case, here's another sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyObject myobj = new MyObject("prop1", "prop2");
        object[] obj_array = { myobj };

        foreach (object obj in obj_array)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Property Name: " + property.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Property Value: " + property.GetValue(obj));
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
public class MyObject
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public MyObject(string p1, string p2)
    {
        Property1 = p1;
        Property2 = p2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try: `Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", attrs) );`

Comment: that's array of object, witch contains properties and its value, and that what I need to print it out